# Write one or more triggers to manage the grade attribute of new Highschoolers

Tags: mysql

If the inserted tuple has a value less than 9 or greater than 12, change the value to NULL. On the other hand, if the inserted tuple has a null value for grade, change it to 9. ```

```
CREATE TRIGGER gradeTrigger1
AFTER INSERT ON highschooler 
WHEN new.grade < 9 OR new.grade > 12 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE highschooler SET grade=NULL WHERE id=new.id; 
END
```

Comment: use a **before Insert** trigger you can't change table that has fired the trigger. with the before Insert you can achieve the same result

Comment: Using a Stored Procedure (instead of a Trigger) may give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment.

For your purpose you can use a [BEFORE  INSERT trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `gradeTrigger1` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON highschooler  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CASE  WHEN  new.grade < 9 OR new.grade > 12  THEN
        SET new.grade = NULL;
    WHEN  new.grade IS NULL THEN
        SET new.grade = 9;
    ELSE
        SET new.grade = NEW.grade;
    END CASE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Completion time: 2020-03-27T21:34:40.5360262+08:00

Comment: I removed the use statement. See if this solves your problem, at least in Workbench it does.